Need to add substring from colum, column and custom value but returns 0
I need to update the value of a column that should equal to initial from name + last name + "@simuladores"
The name column is called nombre_jefe, the last name column is called apellido_jefe, and the column it should be added to is called email_empresa.
The problem is, everytime I try something and it goes through it just returns 0 in every row.
All the columns are type VARCHAR
I tried:
UPDATE sector SET email_empresa = (SUBSTR(nombre_jefe, 1, 1) || apellido_jefe || "@simuladores.com.ar");

SELECT * FROM sector;
but it returns me:



nombre_jefe
apellido_jefe
email_empresa




John
Gomez
0


Juan
Perez
0


Emily
Torres
0



It should end up with something like this



nombre_jefe
apellido_jefe
email_empresa




John
Gomez
jgomez@simuladores


Juan
Perez
jperez@simuladores


Emily
Torres
etorres@simuladores




What are the data types, please show the full table definition.

Either use concat instead of ||, or set sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT.  By default, || is a logical OR.

@Andrew Ah it's MySQL being "helpful" as usual https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=fe0bb360-26c1-423f-a8e7-48c087b966f5
